# Jenkinsfile copyartifact cannot find artifact when using filter criteria with wildcard

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, branch

I have 2 jobs with 2 different jenkinsfile.
A job can generate artifacts correctly with:

```
post {
      always {
          mstest testResultsFile:"testresults*.trx", keepLongStdio: true
          archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'from/path/Deploy/**/*.*', fingerprint: true
```

I use these artifacts in another job, copying with:

```
        steps {          
          step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', fingerprintArtifacts: true, flatten: true, projectName: 'branch/name', selector: lastSuccessful(), filter: "webpackage.*", target: './artifacts'])
```

When I run without 'filter' criteria, all artifacts are copied. When I use 'filter' as used above, I have this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to copy artifacts from branch/name with filter: webpackage.*
```

Jenkins and agent are running on Windows SO.
Should I specify path diferrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation CopyArtifact uses ant expression syntax. Hence this probably works on paths. Also I would skip the dot.

```
    steps {          
      step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', fingerprintArtifacts: true, flatten: true, projectName: 'branch/name', selector: lastSuccessful(), filter: "**/webpackage*", target: './artifacts'])
```